# Reading a csv file in a flask app using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chart.js

I would like to create a charts.js chart in my flask app. To do that, I believe I need to read a csv file containing the data I need using D3.

The problem: reading directly in the JS file returns `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/resources/stroke_freq_df.csv 404 (NOT FOUND)` in the console log, the problem is the same when I try to add an end point with the csv data.

**charts.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %}

<div style="padding: 5%">
  <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
  <h1>Bar Chart</h1>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**base.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- website Title -->
    <title>Kanji</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap 5.2 CSS -->

    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- Icons -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />

    <!-- Local CSS -->
    <link
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='CSS/base.css') }}"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    {% include "navbar.html" %}

    <!-- Contents will be defined here -->
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}

    <!--**********************************
        Scripts
    ***********************************-->
    <!--JQuery, popper and Bootstrap -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-kjU+l4N0Yf4ZOJErLsIcvOU2qSb74wXpOhqTvwVx3OElZRweTnQ6d31fXEoRD1Jy"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- charts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

    <!--Local JS -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='JS/charts.js') }}"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Reading directly - charts.js (absolute path also does not work):**

```
d3.csv('../resources/stroke_freq_df.csv',function(data){
    console.log(data)
})
```

**Using Flask end point**
**charts.js:**

```
d3.csv('/send_csv',function(data){
    console.log(data)
})
```

**app.py:**

```
...

@app.route('/charts', methods=["GET"])
def method_name():
    return render_template('charts.html')

@app.route('/send_csv1',methods=["GET"])
def send_csv():
    file_name = request.files['/resources/stroke_freq_df.csv']
    with open(file_name) as file:
        csv_file = csv.reader(file)
    return send_file(csv_file, as_attachment=False)
...
```

I am not sure if I even have to use a flask endpoint, I have seen one tutorial loading it directly but I cannot replicate how they did it.

The end goal here is to pass data in the csv file into a charts.js framework. Nothing I do seems to work and as far as I know you can't directly use csv files in charts.js. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use d3 to get the csv data, if you want to use the data in chart.js? If the csv file is on the server, then you need to make a request to the server for it. If it is accessible directly from the front, then you can use fetch API to get the file content.

Comment: @Geshcode I've watched several tutorials and every single one of them stated that charts.js does not read csv files and it has to be read through d3 first. The csv file is on my computer.

Comment: Chart.js doesn't read the files, but chart.js doesn't need d3 to function. They are two different libraries, which can be used to create charts. Like I wrote before, you can use fetch to either access the file directly or make a HTTP request to the server side of the application.

I know, that the file is on your computer. The question is, if it is on the server side or front side of the application.

Comment: Thank you taking the time to provide more details. I don't know how to do these things or how they are different, but I have something to research now.

I wish I could understand why I can't even read the csv file using d3.js where every tutorial uses this format and have zero problems.

Comment: Not related to your question: both your "reading directly" and "using flask" `d3.csv` methods are incorrect, the way you're doing it with a callback worked only for v4 or lower. It returns a promise, so it has to be `d3.csv(file).then(...)`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you! I was commenting out the ```.then(...)``` part to see if I could see the data in the console log. Still did not work, but at least one step closer.